# set json property depending on child property

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-send-api

I am creating this JSON object

```
 {
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "generic",
            "image_aspect_ratio": "square"
            "elements": [
                new CreateBallon(results[rand])
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set the `image_aspect_ratio` in only if `elements[0].someProp` is present. 
How can I do that?

Comment: write a conditional statement: `"image_aspect_ratio": myObj.attachment.payload.elements[0] === someProp ? square : ''`

Comment: can I write `this.attachment.payload` instead of `myObj.attachment.payload` because i am reffering to current object ?

Comment: You cannot refer to `this` until the object  is fully constructed

Comment: so I can first create and save the JSON object, then check if that property exists, then I can edit it again to set `image_aspect_ratio` right??

Comment: yup. Just set `image_aspect_ratio = ""` when creating object and change its value after that if your condition is true

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @ParteekDheri let me know if you be able to do that successfully

Comment: @Usman Rana Thanks, I was able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clear what `JSON` is. It is a textual notation for data. If you do anything with the object that involves code of `Javascript` don't call it `JSON` so, The object you're talking about is not a `JSON` but a `JavaScript` object created via object literal notation.

Now to answer your query, you can't refer to `this` object before you've fully initialized that object. So what you can do is initialize your object with some default value and then you should be able to edit any property based on the properties from the same object. Something like

```
 var obj = {"property1" : "X", "property2" : ""};
```

Now you can update your object like

```
  obj.property2 = obj.property1 =='yourCondition' ? 'NewValue' : obj.property2
```